# carriage-return character ^M in json file when using docker cp

Tags: docker, carriage-return

My host is windows and I am using docker desktop. When I use the command `docker cp` to copy files from windows to the container which is Ubuntu the json file would end up containing the carriage-return character (i.e.^M). How can I remove them?

**Impediments:**

1. `docker cp` windows command would copy the json as read-only by root
2. Docker image pull from somewhere and I only have access to user jovyan whom do not have permission to `chmod`. `docker exec -u 0` would return error `Error response from daemon: Multiple IDs found with provided prefix: 0` so I can't just login as root either.
3. Tried WinSCP to move the file to the container but return error say "Remote side unexpectedly closed network connection". I am using SFTP with hostname as localhost and port no. filled. I left password blank as I don't think there is password required for user jovyan since `docker exec` would connect to this user directly without asking password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^M` is the keyboard equivalent of the `\r` character. `sed` is a program installed by default in Ubuntu distros so you should be able to run this to remove these characters from the json file in your Ubuntu container:

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' FILENAME
```

If you want to know what the command does, here's the info:

- `sed` is a stream editor that can change files
- `-i` means to make modifications in place
- `s/\r$//` is a replacement expression saying to replace `\r` at the end of lines (`$` signifies the end of a line) with nothing

Comment: Just copied and pasted your code, switched the FILENAME of course. Voilà! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer here is to install conversion programs that will convert the line endings and deal with the pesky carriage returns for you, dos2unix is always a good shout.

Install:

```
sudo apt install dos2unix
```

Usage:

```
dos2unix <filename>
```

Comment: ls \*.\* | xargs dos2unix